# FatalError failed to execute script. PyQt5

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, python-import, pyinstaller

I know that questions have already been raised on this topic, but I believe that all decisions were strictly individual. The essence of the problem:
There is a calculator.py script and a kalkulator.py These files are in the same directory, the calculator file is executable, this is the file that I convert into an EXE using PyInstaller. Inside the file, I import several PyQt5 libraries, and the second file is Python: **from kalkulator import ***
The second file kalkulator.py contains the GUI of the program created with QtDesigner

When i run the command **pyinstaller --onefile --debug calculator.py** everything goes fine.

But when I run the EXE program file in debug mode, I see the following error:

[image]

The photo shows that the following error occurs.
"DLL Load Failed: The specified procedure could not be found."

I can assume that the problem is that when assembling, PyInstaller does not see the file kalkulator.py it contains a graphical interface.

What can you say about this problem, how do you think you can solve it?

I use:
Python 3.5
PyQt5
PyInstaller 3.3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem! I changed the version of Python 3.5.0 to 3.6.0, and also reinstalled PyQt5.